# how to use tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update in tf.Session well?

Tags: python, tensorflow, session, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have an array (called: **images**) with this shape `(9, 28, 28, 3)` and another (called: **modifiers**) with this `(9, 10, 10, 3)`.
So now I want to put the elements sized 10x10 from **modifiers** (all the 9) into **images** in a specific coordinate `(x, y)`. How can I do that using the function `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` (or another better) in a `tf.Session()`? 
Below a tiny example I want to do!

[image: example with small arrays]

Comment: @jdehesa can you help me?

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using?